# g++ searches /lib/../lib/, then /lib/

Tags: linux, g++, ubuntu-9.04

According to `g++ -print-search-dirs` my C++ compiler is searching for libraries in many directories, including ...

- /lib/../lib/:
- /usr/lib/../lib/:
- /lib/:
- /usr/lib/

Naively, `/lib/../lib/` would appear to be the same directory as `/lib/` — lib's parent will have a child named lib, "that man's father's son is my father's son's son" and all that.  The same holds for `/usr/lib/../lib/` and `/usr/lib/`

1. Is there some reason, perhaps having to do with symbolic links, that g++ ought to be configured to search both `/lib/../lib/` and `/lib/`?
2. If this is unnecessary redundancy, how would one go about fixing it?

If it matters, this was observed on an unmodified install of Ubuntu 9.04.

Edit: More information.

The results are from executing `g++ -print-search-dirs` with no other switches, from a bash shell.

Neither LIBRARY_PATH nor LPATH are output from `printenv`, and both `echo $LPATH` and `echo LIBRARY_PATH` return blank lines.

Comment: A good question - you should see what my MinGW library path looks like, and I have no idea why!

Answer (score 4):

An attempt at an answer (which I gathered from a few minutes of looking at the `gcc.c` driver source and the Makefile environment).

These paths are constructed in runtime from:

1. GCC exec prefix (see [GCC documentation](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gcc-3.0.2/html_node/gcc_53.html) on `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`)
2. The `$LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable
3. The `$LPATH` environment variable (which is treated like `$LIBRARY_PATH`)
4. Any values passed to `-B` command-line switch
5. Standard executable prefixes (as specified during compilation time)
6. Tooldir prefix

The last one (tooldir prefix) is usually defined to be a relative path:
From gcc's `Makefile.in`

```
# Directory in which the compiler finds libraries etc.
libsubdir = $(libdir)/gcc/$(target_noncanonical)/$(version)
# Directory in which the compiler finds executables
libexecsubdir = $(libexecdir)/gcc/$(target_noncanonical)/$(version)
# Used to produce a relative $(gcc_tooldir) in gcc.o
unlibsubdir = ../../..
....
# These go as compilation flags, so they define the tooldir base prefix
# as ../../../../, and the one of the library search prefixes as ../../../
# These get PREFIX appended, and then machine for which gcc is built
# i.e i484-linux-gnu, to get something like: 
# /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.3/../../../../i486-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/
DRIVER_DEFINES = \
-DSTANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX=\"$(unlibsubdir)/\" \
-DTOOLDIR_BASE_PREFIX=\"$(unlibsubdir)/../\" \
```

However, these are for compiler-version specific paths. Your examples are likely affected by the environment variables that I've listed above (`LIBRARY_PATH`, `LPATH`)

Comment: @ASk, I checked for LIBRARY_PATH and LPATH in the environment (bash), and neither is defined.  Tracing the g++ source should be guaranteed to terminate with the resolution of this mystery; thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, theoretically, if /lib was a symlink to /drive2/foo, then /lib/../lib would point to /drive2/lib if I'm not mistaken. Theoretically...

Edit: I just tested and it's not the case - it comes back to /lib. Hrm :(