# Priority of LIBRARY_PATH with custom gcc installations

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, ld

Is there a way to get compilers to prefer libraries from `LIBRARY_PATH` instead of system paths. I am particularly looking for Clang. I partially solved the problem for GCC while writing this question, but it's also not quite clear.

#### Background

`LIBRARY_PATH` is a convenient environment variable to allow **transparently** linking libraries in non-standard directories, e.g. user installations, and in my case environment modules that provide **different versions** of a library.
The idea is to do a `module load libfoo/version` and the compiler will transparently use the right `libfoo.so`.

For a shared library, one also needs to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `ld.so` to find the right library. If there are multiple `libfoo.so` in both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/usr/lib`, `ld.so` specifies that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched before default paths.

#### Problem

I have encountered issues when the library defines a `soname` - which is different between the two `libfoo.so` versions (which are symlinks to `libfoo.so.1` and `libfoo.so.2` respectively) in `/usr/lib` and `LIBRARY_PATH`. Then `ld` will link against the `soname` in `/usr/lib` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can no longer prioritize the intended library.

I first encountered this with boost, but here's a small example:

```
echo "void foo() {}" > foo.c

# create an old libfoo version in /usr/lib
sudo gcc foo.c -fpic -shared -o /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1 -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1
sudo ln -s libfoo.so.1 /usr/lib/libfoo.so

# create the new libfoo that we want to transparently override
mkdir -p /tmp/XXX/lib
gcc foo.c -fpic -shared -o /tmp/XXX/lib/libfoo.so.2 -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.2
ln -s libfoo.so.2 /tmp/XXX/lib/libfoo.so

export LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/XXX/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/XXX/lib

echo "void foo(); int main() { foo(); }" > main.c
gcc main.c -lfoo
ldd a.out| grep foo
    # under some conditions this shows libfoo.so.1 instead of .2
    libfoo.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
```

#### GCC

I initially encountered this issue with a custom installation of GCC while it was working as expected for the system installation.
`gcc --print-search-dirs` reveals a pattern:

```
/tmp/XXX/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/tmp/XXX/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/tmp/XXX/lib/../lib64/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../lib64/
/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/lib/../lib64/
/usr/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/../lib64/
/tmp/XXX/lib/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/
/opt/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../
/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

In addition to the normal search priority - where `LIBRARY_PATH` comes before system paths, GCC prioritizes a few "prefixes", including `../lib64`. This can be worked around by creating another symlink:

```
ln -s lib /tmp/XXX/lib64
```

I thought this was related to the `--libdir` parameter during `configure`, which I omitted and is `/usr/lib` in the system installation, but even if i specify `--libdir=$PREFIX/lib --libexecdir=$PREFIX/lib`, it prefers `../lib64`.

**How to compile or control `gcc` at runtime so that it at least uses the  `../lib` instead of `../lib64` postfix?**

#### Clang

Clang is even more uncooperative. It does not include `LIBRARY_PATH` in the output for `--print-search-dirs` and does not even include a `-L/tmp/XXX/lib` to it's call to `ld` if the `libfoo.so` can be found already in `/usr/lib`.

**How can I get Clang to prioritize my library path transparently?**

#### Notes

- Examples are from Archlinux, but I also tested under Ubuntu 16.04 which behaves similarly.
- Related questions for GCC: [Why does g++ look in LIBRARY_PATH/../lib64 and where is this documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419363/why-does-g-look-in-library-path-lib64-and-where-is-this-documented) and [g++ searches /lib/../lib/, then /lib/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990370/g-searches-lib-lib-then-lib).
- Overriding the search order with `-L` works, but is not transparent.
- `gcc --print-search-dirs` lists more directories than `gcc -v`. The latter filters out non-exiting paths.

Comment: One particularly ugly but working solution is making a wrapper around `gcc`, `cc`, `g++` and `c++` and forcing appropriate `-L` there.

Comment: A custom specs file could solve your problem. Please see `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html` for details

Comment: @nit I'm not sure where to start in this file. There's only 4 mentions of 'library/ies' and none of them seem to refer to my issue. Could you maybe elaborate in form of an answer?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not beyond what is written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition to the normal search priority - where LIBRARY_PATH comes before system paths, GCC prioritizes a few "prefixes", including ../lib64.

This is **not normal GCC behaviour**, which is probably why it's also not the behaviour you see for Clang.

As documented [in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#index-LIBRARY_005fPATH), the directories specified by `LIBRARY_PATH` are passed to `ld` *after* the directories explicitly named with `-L` options:

> The value of `LIBRARY_PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories, much like PATH. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if it cannot find them using `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`. **Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first).**

The behaviour you're seeing where these paths come first is not how GCC usually behaves:

```
/tmp/XXX/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/
/tmp/XXX/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/tmp/XXX/lib/../lib64/
```

This seems to be caused by a patch to GCC used by Debian (and inherited by Ubuntu) [as observed by @facetus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60364259/981959). That patch seems to be intended to make GCC more compatible with the Debian [MultiArch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) directory hierarchy, where libs are in an arch-specific sub-directory like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` rather than just in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`. As a side effect of those patches, you can "trick" gcc into looking in your preferred directories first with the right combination of symlinks that match the extra dirs Debian searches first.

One of the comments suggests a cleaner solution would be to use GCC [Spec Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html). You could create a simple specs file that modifies the default `*link` spec and then tell gcc to use that via `-specs=yourspecsfile` e.g. something like:

```
%rename link                 orig_link

*link:
-L/your/custom/libs %(orig_link)
```

Alternatively, I think you could make that the default behaviour by configuring gcc with:

```
--with-specs="%{m64:-L/your/custom/libs}"
```

I've used other custom specs this way, although not this specific example. I think this should mean that every time your custom gcc is compiling (or assembling or linking) some 64-bit code, it will add the `-L/your/custom/libs` option. I think that should do what you want for a self-built GCC.

But I have no idea how to get Clang to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why a custom installation of GCC is different. Debian distribution patches the GCC makefiles, that's how it gets the right priority of `LIBRARY_PATH`. Before building GCC, find `gcc/config/i386/t-linux64` and there change all `MULTILIB_OSDIRNAMES` to these lines:

```
MULTILIB_OSDIRNAMES = m64=../lib$(call if_multiarch,:x86_64-linux-gnu)
MULTILIB_OSDIRNAMES+= m32=../lib32$(call if_multiarch,:i386-linux-gnu)
MULTILIB_OSDIRNAMES+= mx32=../libx32$(call if_multiarch,:x86_64-linux-gnux32)
```

Also add `--libexecdir=/your/custom/path/lib --libdir=/your/custom/path/lib` to `configure`.